# gettext of string with number

Tags: php, text, numbers, gettext

I would like to use gettext to translate a sentence and leave number as it is, like in these examples:

```
"i am 100 years old" -> Tengo 100 años de edad (spanish)
"i am 10 years old"   -> Tengo 10 años de edad (spanish)

"i slept 24 hours a day" ->  Ich schlief 24 Stunden am Tag (german)
"i slept 4 hours a day" ->   Ich schlief 4 Stunden am Tag (german)
```

I guess the string should be something like this: `'i slept #24# hours a day'` but I'm not sure...

Is there any way to translate string regardless the specific number in it (some kind of formatting maybe)?

Comment: You can get numbers using `preg_match`. And here's regex for it `!\d+!`.

Comment: getting the numbers will not solve the problem and provide a good solution..

I would like to save typing translations for all combinations: "i slept 24 hours a day" , "i slept 23 hours a day" , "i slept 22 hours a day" , "i slept 21 hours a day" ....

Comment: If I thought that this is solution, I would not comment it. I've just "thrown" an idea.

Comment: saving time of typing all options exists with only numbers changed in it is something i would like to avoid of.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you talk about is more-o-less easily solved with this:

```
$translation = gettext("I am %d years old");
$phrase      = sprintf($translation, $n);
```

But there's another problem actually. In some languages nouns that follow numbers ("year" in your example) are translated different depending of what number is used. And it's not only about single/plural form: for example, in Russian

```
"I am 10 years old" = "Мне 10 лет"
"I am 21 years old" = "Мне 21 год"
```

For these types of translation you should use more advanced [ngettext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ngettext.php)() function, like this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'cs_CZ');
printf(ngettext("%d window", "%d windows", 1), 1); // 1 okno
printf(ngettext("%d window", "%d windows", 2), 2); // 2 okna
printf(ngettext("%d window", "%d windows", 5), 5); // 5 oken
```

Yes, the number itself is used twice: first to get the correct form of noun in `ngettext`, then to fill the placeholder in `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

If you always know the format, [`sscanf`](http://php.net/sscanf.php) can help you.

```
sscanf('i am %d years old', $years);
$newString = sprintf('Tengo %d años de edad', $years);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use replace the number after translate.

```
str_replace('#NUM#', $num,  gettext('i slept #NUM# hours a day'));
```